# Computer shuts down, how to reduce temperatute?

Tags: cooling, temperature, hp-envy

It has i7 @1.60 GHz 120GB SSD 
windows 10

I am using the laptop for about 7 years.

Its fan was never replaced, it makes very noise and shuts down in order to decrease temperature.

Temperature of at least one core becomes +90C. It was enough to shut down soon.

**How can i decrease temperature?**

Should i replace new fan.should i install windows 7 again or should i buy a cooler, im talking about outer thing not inside.Do they differ?
Thanks.

Not: I used thermal paste twice in last 4 years.

Comment: Your fan might be blocked by dusts. Clean it, or take it to a shop to get it cleaned. If that doesn't help, make sure when you are operating it, the ventilation passage doesn't get blocked. After that, you can consider buying a cooling fan.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I forgot to say that i cleaned fan. If it works, i will buy a new fan i think.

Answer (score 0):

I had a HP Pavilion dv6 a while back which had the same issue. When I gave it for diagnostics, turns out the power supply module was not working correctly and was causing the CPU to overheat. 
Might wanna check it out